# laravel migration error while creating new one

Tags: laravel

i tried creating new migration and in my migration file i got the following text

```
/**
 * Gets the first element of `array`.
 *
 * @static
 * @memberOf _
 * @since 0.1.0
 * @alias first
 * @category Array
 * @param {Array} array The array to query.
 * @returns {*} Returns the first element of `array`.
 * @example
 *
 * _.head([1, 2, 3]);
 * // => 1
 *
 * _.head([]);
 * // => undefined
 */
function head(array) {
  return (array && array.length) ? array[0] : undefined;
}
```

module.exports = head;

instead of the normal migration code,

i tried installing the composer , composer dump-autoload
tried clearing cache
but still no luck , it was not like this earlier as i have created many migrations and they were working fine but suddenly it gave me this error,

any idea what is causing this error

Comment: You need to show more code. What file is the code above situated in?

Comment: the code appears in my new migration file , the new migration file is in the migrations directory

Comment: Okay so what does the code does? Cos the following code does not appear in any newly generated migration file

Comment: i have no idea what it does , that is why i am asking , it suddenly started appearing in my new migrations and i can't even run the migration even after editing it

Comment: Basically the reason why it's giving error is because those are javascript codes inside php files. Try to copy a valid migration code and delete all of this to see if your migrations will work

Comment: getting   Cannot declare class CreateSample, because the name is already in use and their is no file with such name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237216/discussion-between-nabeel-siddiqui-and-patrick-obafemi).